# Linux/Ubuntu faking a network connection

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have a couple of programs that talk t each other through HTTP. I have a main program that is a HTTP server that acts as a browser for other programs to query.

Everything works fine if... I have an internet connection on my machine, but when I disconnect the cable, eth0 goes down and I can't connect to anything.

In windows all I need is a loopback network card and I am set.

In my ubuntu box (10.10) I still have lo connected with it's assigned IP but I can't force eth0 to go up.

How can I have a working connection without being connected?! 
Can I fake a connection?

Cheers
André Moreira

---

some clarification, the first thing I am doing is trying to send a broadcast to discover what other apps are on the same network.

This is failing because the network is unreachable. Try to unplug you cable and ping to 255.255.255.255...

I guess that when I "solve this" everything will fall into place.

Comment: It'd be useful if you posted the code from your programs.  Are they using the `lo` address, or the IP `eth0` had?

Comment: Well, all I need is an interface I can talk to and I can't seem to find a way to fake one

Answer (score 2):

There is a loopback in Linux, and it has an IP address (like all IP based network interfaces).

Just connect to `127.0.0.1`, or `localhost` if your network configuration hasn't been customized to not follow the standard.

Often the alias for the loopback interface is `lo` and here is a typical entry from `ifconfig`

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6026819 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6026819 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2106315659 (1.9 GiB)  TX bytes:2106315659 (1.9 GiB)
```